# Multiple (of the same) UIView on UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I want to have a `UIScrollView` that contains a `UIView` that is repeated every time the `UIScrollView` pages to the right or left, loading different data (dynamically from a server) each time.

Is there a way this can be done in IB? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with with Interface Builder. You have to do it programmatically. Here is the easy way to do this.

If each page you swipe to has the same layout but different data then you can create what the view should look like in Interface Builder. You are going to need to use the scrollview delegate so you can have access to:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

What you need to do in here is
1) Determine the current page

```
CGPoint offsetPoint = scrollView.contentOffset;
float fractionalPage = offsetPoint.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = lround(fractionalPage);
```

2) Determine which direction (left or right) I do this by using a `int scrollViewPosition;` variable

3) Remove the view (say we moved to the right) that is two position to the left

3) Add a the view that would be next (the next view to the right).

4) Populate the view

There are things that will help performance here. 
1) Reuse views. When you remove the view from the scrollview repopulate it with new data and add it back on to the view.

Comment: Do you have a more detailed tutorial on reusing the views?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is not possible by using Interface Builder.

Doing such scroll view manually will be not very easy task.
I think easiest solution is to use UITableView rotated to Pi/2 (90 degrees).

There is very useful tutorial on raywenderlich.com. Here is [Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) and [Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2). You can start from Part 2 as they just build vertical UITableView in the Part 1.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this kind of behavior using IB.

Doing what you want with a UIScrollView, in code is not that difficult. You need to understand the basics though. There are several WWDC videos about UIScrollViews available on Apples developer pages, so you might want to check those out, they will point you in the right direction.